# Возврат и вывод значения input

Tags: javascript

```html
<input type="radio" id="m">M
<input type="radio" id="w">M
<button id="go">GO</button>
```

```js
document.getElementById("go").onclick = go;
let m = document.getElementById("m").checked;
let w = document.getElementById("w").checked;

function go (){
    let massege = m == true ? "hello Man" : w == true ? "hello Wooman": "who are you;
    alert(massage);
}
```

Подскажите, что я не правильно делаю? Если в input radio поставлю галочку, оно ведь будет `true`?

Comment: Где у вас элементы с `id = "radioMaleM"` и `id = "radioMaleW"`?

Comment: не верно id присвоил, уже исправил

Comment: У вас 2 синтаксические ошибки в примере. Запустите ваш пример и смотрите консоль (devTools).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам стоит перенести объявление ваших переменных в функцию go:

```
function go (){
    let m = document.getElementById("m").checked;
    let w = document.getElementById("w").checked;
    let message = m ? "hello Man" : w ? "hello Wooman": "who are you?";
    alert(message);
}
```

Comment: Вы проверили ваш пример? В нем 2 синтаксических ошибки.

Comment: Я копировал из оригинала. Думаю синтаксические ошибки - это просто ошибки в вопросе. Не думаю, что код неработает из-за этого

Comment: `m == true` — нет смысла сравнивать с true... в логическм контексте оно и так будет принимать true или false... можно писать просто `m ? "Hello" : w ? "Woman" : "Who are you"`

Comment: Согласен. Пожалуй внесу правки в ответ )

Comment: да, все верно, заработало... но а если я хочу сделать их глобальными ? а не держать внутри функции ?(

Comment: @user3265030 судя по вопросу ТС у него вполне могут быть синтаксические ошибки. Если вы можете добавить хороший, работающий пример - от этого только все выиграют.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko внес правки.

Comment: @PavelMasalov Как вариант, можно добавить обработчики на нажатие этих input, которые будут обновлять ваши глобальные переменные.

Comment: Ловите +1 от меня.

Answer (score 2):

Но как только таких элементов станет чуть больше двух - задолбаетесь прописывать условия)
Можно использовать объект со всеми необходимыми значениями.

```js
document.getElementById("go").onclick = go;

let genders = {
  m: "Hello Man!",
  w: "Hello Woman!",
}

function go (){
  let g = document.querySelector(".gender:checked");
  console.log( g ? genders[ g.dataset.gender ] : "Who are you?" );
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="gender" data-gender="m" name="gender">M
<input type="radio" class="gender" data-gender="w" name="gender">W
<button id="go">GO</button>
```